# Scala break out of map

Tags: scala

I need to break out of a seq map when a condition is met something like this where `foo` would return a list of objects where the size depends on how long it takes to find the targetId

```
def foo(ids: Seq[String], targetId: String) = ids.map(id => getObject(id)).until(id == targetId)
```

obviously the until method does not exist but I am looking for something that does the equivalent

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No need to create intermediate stream/iterator/view.

Just call  `takeWhile` first:

```
 ids.takeWhile(_ != targetId).map(getObject)
```

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 ways I use:

1) replace `map` with a recursive call that processes things in certain way. Pretty handy if there are some complex side-effects.

2) use `Stream` or `Iterator` and `takeWhile` to evaluate it's elements lazily and terminate once the condition is met. I would go with this variant since it will be close to the first option - but much more consise.

Answer (score 1):

Since the RDD I was playing with was small, I achieved the same using take(n).