# Stop processing maps in Scala

Tags: scala

In the following code, I need to stop processing the map if the element = 2:

```
val seq = Seq(1,2,3)

seq.map { x => if (x==2) /* stop processing the map */  }
```

is this possible?

Comment: You can use `takeWhile`. For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33294354/9297144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `map()` directly as `map()` is designed to work over the entire collection, but you can split the collection into 2 parts and apply the `map()` to one and not the other.

```
val seq = Seq(0,1,2,3,3,2,1,0)
val (before, after) = seq.span(_ != 2)
before.map(_ + 70) ++ after  //res0: Seq[Int] = List(70, 71, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0)
```