# Break loop if Either function returns Left

Tags: scala, monads, future, either

In the following code, what I need is to stop processing the loop if either `either1` or `either2` return Left, and if that happens then `mainFunction` has to return Left as well. Also, the string returned by `either1.Left` or `either2.Left` needs to be returned by `mainFunction.Left`. How to make this work?

```
def either1 (i:Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future {
                    if (i<3)
                       Right(i*2)
                    else
                       Left("error 1")
}

def either2 (i:Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future {
                    if (i>3)
                       Right(i*2)
                    else
                       Left("error 2")
}


val seq = Seq ( 1,1,2,2,3,4,5 )

def mainFunction: Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future {

     val seq2 = seq.map { number =>
             if (number % 2 == 0)
                  either1(number) // <-- this needs to break the loop if it returns Left
             else
                  either2(number) // <-- this needs to break the loop if it returns Left
        }

    Right(seq2.length)  // <-- seq2 is a sequence of Futures
}
```

Comment: "The loop" is what? The `seq.map` function? What is it supposed to return? An `Either[List[Future[whatever]]]` is not a `Future[Either[String, Int]]]`. How did you want to reduce the list of ints into a single int?

Comment: Yes, the loop is the `seq.map` function. It doesn't matter what it returns, the focus of the question is the loop and the fact that `mainFunction` needs to return a `Left`.

Comment: The problem with your posted code is that methods `either1()` and `either2()` don't return `Either[]`. They return `Future[Either[]]` and the only way to halt iteration based on the `Either` status is to wait for the `Future` to complete, which defeats the point of launching the `Future` in the first place.

Comment: @jwvh The [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825409/stop-processing-maps-in-scala) indicates that the OP actually wants to process the elements one after another, but asynchronously, without blocking. I don't see how it defeats the point of launching the Future? You sequentially post a series of requests to an asynchronously answering service, meanwhile your app can do something else. Perfectly valid use case for futures, imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below keeps iterating over the sequence until it encounters the first error, and returns the error message, or the fixed number `42` (that's the "doesn't matter what it returns"-requirement).

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def either1(i: Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future {
  if (i < 3) Right(i * 2)
  else Left("error 1")
}

def either2 (i:Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future {
  if (i > 3) Right(i * 2)
  else Left("error 2")
}

val seq = Seq(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val doesntMatter = 42

/** Returns either first error message returned by `either1` or
  * `either2`, or the fixed number `doesntMatter`.
  */
def mainFunction: Future[Either[String, Int]] = {
  def recHelper(remaining: List[Int]): Future[Either[String, Int]] = {
    remaining match {
      case Nil => Future { Right(doesntMatter) }
      case h :: t => (if (h % 2 == 0) either1(h) else either2(h)).flatMap {
        headEither =>
        headEither match {
          case Left(s) => Future { Left(s) }
          case Right(n) => recHelper(t)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  recHelper(seq.toList)
}

val res = mainFunction
Thread.sleep(2000)
println(res) // Future(Success(Left(error 2)))
```

If you do this significantly more often than once, consider taking a look at [Scala Cats' EitherT](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html), and also at the method `tailRecM` defined specifically for such use cases on all monadic typeclasses.

Comment: Can you please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842113/recursively-returning-a-concatenation-of-future-right) ?

Comment: @peterSc does it really make any sense to post it as a new question? You've been asked in the comments under this question what you want as result. First you said that "it doesn't matter". Now all of sudden you want the whole `Seq[Int]`. And what happened to indentation, I've already repaired the formatting in this code once, is there any reason to post the version with broken formatting again?

Comment: I posted the new question because you answered this one, it didn't make sense to change the current question.

Comment: @peterSc Ok, fair enough. I probably wouldn't want to update this answer either. Alright, I take a look at the other one.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala the standard collections don’t provide a method for that.
You can user either scala.util.control.Breaks or you have to write the 
recursion, something like this

```
val seq = Seq(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5)

def either1(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {
    if (i < 3) Right(i * 2)
    else Left("error 1")
}

def either2(i: Int): Either[String, Int] = {
    if (i > 3) Right(i * 2)
    else Left("error 2")
}

def rec(seq: Seq[Int], acc: Seq[Either[String, Int]]): Seq[Either[String, Int]] = seq match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: xs =>
        val xx = if (x % 2 == 0) either1(x) else either2(x)
        xx match {
            case Left(_) => acc
            case Right(value) => rec(xs, acc :+ Right(value))
        }
    }

rec(seq, Seq())
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether using `Break` with `Future`s is a good idea, because it would throw control-flow exceptions on stacks in different threads in the thread-pool. That's most probably not what you want.

Comment: I totaly agree about using Break with Future. For simplicity i have provided solution without Future wrapping.

Comment: Well, yeah, making everything sequential and single threaded certainly does simplify quite a few things. But simply dropping all the `Future`s from asynchronous `Future`-based code seems a rather radical simplification. I mean, OP's code lives in `EitherT[Future, String, A]`, you instead just used `Either[String, A]` everywhere. How does it help if `either1` and `either2` cannot be made non-asynchronous, because they are provided by some external api?

Answer (score 0):

I generally avoid recursive functions if a library function will do what I want.

In this case we can use `takeWhile` to take all the leading elements that are `Right`. However the `map` call will still process every element of the `Seq` so you need to use `view` to evaluate this lazily:

```
val seq2 = seq.view.map { number =>
   if (number % 2 == 0)
     either1(number)
   else
     either2(number)
 }.takeWhile(_.isRight)
```

You still have the the problem that your `either` functions actually return a `Future` and therefore can't be tested for `Left` or `Right` until they complete.