# Recursively returning a concatenation of Future.Right

Tags: scala

In the recursive `recHelper` method below I need to return a list of Futures if all the elements returned `Right` else a Future `Left`. Problem is that I cannot concatenate the results. How to make this code work?

```
def either1 (i:Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future {
                    if (i<3)
                       Right(i*2)
                    else
                       Left("error 1")
}

def either2 (i:Int): Future[Either[String,Int]] = Future {
                    if (i<3)
                       Right(i*2)
                    else
                       Left("error 2")
}


val seq = Seq (1,1,2,2)


def recHelper(remaining: List[Int]): Future[Either[String, Seq[Int]]] = {
    remaining match {
      case Nil => Nil
      case h :: t => (if (h % 2 == 0) either1(h) else either2(h)).map {
        headEither =>
            headEither match {
              case Left(s) => Future { Left(s) }
              case Right(n) => Future { n :: recHelper(t) :: Nil } /// ERROR
            }
      }
    }
  }
  recHelper(seq.toList)
```

Comment: `Seq(Int)` is not a type.

Comment: Can you explain why this needs to be so complicated? Why not create a single `Future` that processes the list sequentially, since that is basically what happens anyway? See my answer to your previous question for the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Nil => Nil` case indicates that you should read up again what the `Future` and what the `Either` monads do: `Nil` is inferred to be of type `List[Int]`. It's missing *two* applications of a monadic `unit`, namely:

1. You forgot to wrap it into a `Right` to make it `Either[List[Int]]`
2. You forgot to wrap it into a `Future`, to make it `Future[Either[List[Int]]`

Same applies for the other cases. Here is a version that works:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.util._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def either1(i: Int): Future[Either[String, Int]] = Future {
  if (i<3) Right(i*2)
  else Left("error 1")
}

def either2(i: Int): Future[Either[String, Int]] = Future {
  if (i<3) Right(i*2)
  else Left("error 2")
}

val seq = Seq(1, 1, 2, 2)

def recHelper(remaining: List[Int]): Future[Either[String, List[Int]]] = {
  remaining match {
    case Nil => Future { Right(Nil) }
    case h :: t => for {
      hEith <- (if (h % 2 == 0) either1(h) else either2(h))
      res <- (hEith match {
        case Left(s) => Future { Left(s) }
        case Right(n) => for {
          tEith <- recHelper(t)
        } yield tEith.map(n :: _)
      })
    } yield res
  }
}
recHelper(seq.toList)
```

You can't build a complex nested for-comprehension with two stacked monads by accident. I can only again strongly recommend to take a look at Scala Cats and `EitherT`. They've build the monad transformer libraries not (only) for fun: it's actually quite painful to deal with two stacked monads simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at Scala Cats but I couldn't find an example related to my issue.

Comment: @peterSc I think searching for an example wouldn't be the right approach. Reading their free book, especially the chapter about Monad Transformers, should be easier than trying to extract the ideas from code examples. As you can see above, these code examples aren't that terribly intuitive.

Comment: I used EitherT in the past and it simplified my code a lot. Thanks for the advise, I'll read their book.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution:

```
def recHelper(remaining :Seq[Int]
             ,acc       :Seq[Int] = Seq()
             ) :Future[Either[String, Seq[Int]]] = remaining match {
    case Seq()  => Future(Right(acc))
    case h +: t => (if (h % 2 == 0) either1(h) else either2(h)).flatMap {
        case Left(s) => Future(Left(s))
        case Right(n) => recHelper(t, n +: acc)
    }
}

recHelper(seq)
//res0: Future[Either[String,Seq[Int]]] = Future(Right(List(4, 4, 2, 2)))
```

Comment: Yeah, making it tail-recursive helps avoid one extra `map`, nice. But for heaven's sake, why the haskell-style indentation! Every time you change method name, you have to re-indent all arguments. Every time you change variable name, you have to re-indent all colons... Anyway (+1) for quasi-tail-recursion.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin; Yeah, call me an iconoclast. I find long lines harder to scan and parse visually, especially here on SO where long lines require window scrolling. Here's the _real_ heresy: I've recently  decided I prefer the colon `:` attached to the type instead of the variable. Gotta go. A crowd with torches and pitchforks is headed my way.

Comment: I hate long lines too. But I usually manage to keep my code under 60 characters in width. That does not mean that I have to revert to haskell syntax. `def foo(\nbar: Type1,\nbaz: Cons[T2, T3],\nblah: Type3\n): ReturnType` works perfectly for multiple argument lists and type-arg-lists with generics. Short lines doesn't mean that you have to align them in a way that depends on the length of multiple argument names. That only introduces unnecessary dependencies between the arguments, so it's harder to refactor. I very often align args vertically even if they are short. Who cares about #SLOC anywy